# Is it possible create a "variable" header guard name in C?

Tags: c, header, c-preprocessor

fellow programmers,

I'm new to the C preprocessor and have been recently trying to create a generic-like library in C (as an exercise), and I've come upon a little problem when creating header guards.

All the preprocessor macros are set up so I can include and use my headers like this:

```
#define TYPE int
#include "myheader.h"
#undef TYPE

#define TYPE float
#include "myheader.h"
#undef TYPE

int main(void){
    //Do stuff
    MyFunc_int();

    //More stuff
    MyFunc_float();

    return 0;
}
```

But the problem appears when I need to include the headers in more than one file. Header guards are usually applied in this case, but since the header can be included once -for each type-, neither the usual construction nor `#pragma once` can be used.

My question then is: Is it possible to create a "variable" header guard to work for different `TYPE` definitions?

Comment: I guess in this case you'll have to remove header guards. as their sole purpose is to get a header file included once in a file (c,c++ or any file to be compiled).

Comment: as your sole purpose is to include a header more then once then why bother including those pragmas or guards ?

Comment: by the way nice way to get into the preprocessors.. +1 for that

Comment: The problem is when I have to `#include` it in more than one file for the same type. It gives me the _multiple definition_ error

Comment: What @theadnangondal said.  If we can see what is in `my header.h` we might be able to suggest a better alternative.

Comment: "the problem appears when I need to include the headers in more than one file." - That doesn't seem accurate. It would rather seem the problem appears when you try to eventually include the *same* header more than once in a *single* file. The rest of your assessment certainly seems accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to include the header from various compilation units, you could divide the header into a publich part that plays the role of the header and a private part that plays the role of a `*.c` file, for example:

```
#define M_CONCAT(a, b) a##b

TYPE M_CONCAT(TYPE, _min)(TYPE a, TYPE b);

#ifdef IMPLEMENT

TYPE M_CONCAT(TYPE, _min)(TYPE a, TYPE b)
{
    return (a < b) ? a : b;
}

#endif /* IMPLEMENT */
```

Then you can include this header from multiple files, but you have to make sure that only one file defines `IMPLEMENT` before including the header:

```
#define IMPLEMENT    // only in one file

#define TYPE float
#include "myheader.h"
#undef TYPE

#define TYPE int
#include "myheader.h"
#undef TYPE
```

This file could be a separate compilation unit, `myheader.c`. You must take care to implement the function for all types, however. (But the linker will tell you, which types you've missed.)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

1. Remove the `#include` guards in `myheader.h`.
2. Create different header files for each `TYPE`.

intheader.h:

```
#pragma once

#define TYPE int
#include "myheader.h"
#undef TYPE
```

floatheader.h:

```
#pragma once

#define TYPE float
#include "myheader.h"
#undef TYPE
```

And then use:

```
#include "intheader.h"
#include "floatheader.h"

int main(void){
    //Do stuff
    MyFunc_int();

    //More stuff
    MyFunc_float();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the guards in myheader.h will still not allow this to be included twice

Comment: @theadnangondal, true. You'll have to remove the `#include` guards in `myheader.h`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
#if !defined HEADERGUARD && defined (TYPE==int)
#define HEADERGUARD
<stuff>
#endif
```

You may want to have HEADERGUARD_int and HEADERGUARD_float, depending on what you're doing inside the *.h file.  More conventionally, people will break it into two *.h files.